# Asp.Net Web api: view all logged in users

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I tried to implement the function without success

I want to check if the user's **status** is true so that means he is logged in

I mean if **Status** is false then I do not want to display it at all in a list that will be ignored

What I tried causes all the connected to be displayed even if they are **false**

Model:

```
[Table("Contact")]
public partial class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string ProfilePic { get; set; } = null!;
    public int? Rating { get; set; }
    public bool? Status { get; set; }
    public bool? IsRegistration { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
public virtual DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } = null!;
```

Repository:

```
private readonly TalkBackContactsDbContext _context;

public ContactsRepository(TalkBackContactsDbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public IQueryable<Contact> GetAllConnectedUser(Contact contact)
{

    if (contact.Status == false)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not exist");
    }
    else
    {
        return _context.Contacts;
    }
}
```

api controller:

```
private readonly IContactsRepository _repo;
public ContactsController(IContactsRepository repo)
{
    _repo = repo;
}

[HttpGet()]
public IEnumerable<Contact> GetAllConnected()
{
    var contact = new Contact();

    try
    {
        return _repo.GetAllConnectedUser(contact);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.ToString();
    }
    return _repo.GetAllConnectedUser(contact);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

Repository:

```
private readonly TalkBackContactsDbContext _context;

public ContactsRepository(TalkBackContactsDbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public IEnumerable<Contact> GetAllConnectedUser()
{
    _context.Contacts.Where(a=>a.Status==true).AsEnumerable();
}
```

api controller:

```
 private readonly IContactsRepository _repo;
 public ContactsController(IContactsRepository repo)
 {
     _repo = repo;
 }

[HttpGet()]
public IEnumerable<Contact> GetAllConnected()
{
    return _repo.GetAllConnectedUser();
}
```